# Background для UIView и другие картинки?

Tags: xcode

пользуясь:
[self.view setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"background1.png"]]];

Картинка слижком большая и видно её только четверть видно 640x1136 ! но я её специально делал такой чтобы под ретину 3.5 и ретину 4. Как исправить?

Поставил UIImageView , но в настройке бекграунда я не вижу картинку Main@2x.png, почему тоже не пойму чего)))

и ещё по поводу картинок (контента). я должен делать их больше в 2 раза? или это касаеться только иконок-ярлыков, и заставок?

если у пользователя на 4-м айфоне стоит 7-я прошивка, это же не означает что у него ретина 4?))) верно же?

Благодярю за ответ.

Answer (score 2):

вот две полезные ссылки [о ресурсах](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/App-RelatedResources/App-RelatedResources.html) и [подробнее о картинках](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/recipes/xcode_help-image_catalog-1.0/Recipe.html).
Не надо в ручную задавать размеры картинок, достаточно правильно их назвать, например:

```
background@2x~iphone.png - картинка для iPhone Retina
background~iphone.png - картинка для iPhone
background@2x~ipad.png - картинка для iPad Retina
background~ipad.png - картинка для iPad
```

В коде просто прописываешь `UIImage *background= [UIImage imageWithName:@"background"];` и система сама выберет нужную картинку